# Azure AD Parameter values

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on Azure AD authentication. I always get 401 even though my token is valid. Where can I get the value of Tenant and ValidAudience?

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = 
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication middleware uses a
metadata endpoint which is not supported by the v2.0 endpoint.  Instead, this
OpenIdConnectSecurityTokenProvider implementation can be used to fetch & use the OpenIdConnect metadata document - which for the v2 endpoint is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Check if the audience is intended to be this application
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { clientId, "api://clientId" },

                    // Change below to 'true' if you want this Web API to accept tokens issued to one Azure AD tenant only (single-tenant)
                    // Note that this is a simplification for the quickstart here. You should validate the issuer. For details, 
                    // see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore
                    ValidateIssuer = false,

                },
                new OpenIdConnectSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")
            ),
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the value of tenant and valid audience by modifying your **startup method** like below:

```cs
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"]
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                }
            });
```

The value of **`ida:TenantId`** will be your **Azure AD tenant ID.**

Ensure to add below keys in **`web.config file -> app settings`** before calling startup method.

```cs
<appSettings>

<add key="ida:ClientId" value="[Enter the Application Id (also named ClientId) for the application]" />

<add key="ida:TenantId" value="[Enter the tenant/Directory Id name]" />

<add key="ida:Audience" value="[Enter App ID URI of your application]" />

</appSettings>
```

You can find your **`Application(Client) ID`** and **`Tenant(Directory) ID`** from here:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> App Registrations -> Your Application -> Overview***

[image: Image3]

***After registering the application in Azure AD, set Application ID URI by exposing the API like below:***

[image: Image2]

The value of **`ida:Audience`** will be your **Application ID URI** that will be in the form of **`api://yourappid`**

Make sure to add required scopes to avoid **`401 Error`**.

**Reference:**

[GitHub - Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation#about-this-sample)

[Azure Active Directory - Create Applications, Add Scopes And Add API Access (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-create-applications-add-scopes-and-add-api-access/)

Comment: I still get 401 Error. I follow your steps already

Comment: Have you added required API permissions and scopes for your application?

Comment: Yes, I added this two.  I am getting frustrated now. :(

"user_impersonation"
 "Todo.Read"

Comment: I generate my token using oauth2 token api then use that token to call my API
https://login.microsoftonline.com/39d7d82b-f412-486a-a997-9e45023086e6/oauth2/v2.0/token